# CakePHP can't submit form after encountering a validation error

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

So I have an `add` action for one of my models. There are a few validation rules like "cannot be left blank".

If I fill in the form correctly first time and submit it saves the data succesfully. If I make a validation error however I am alerted to the errors on the form, which is great. I then correct the validation errors and try to resubmit. This time the page just seems to refresh (although the data in the form is repopulated) but the form does not save.

Here is my action in the controller:

```
public function add(  ){
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $this->Sedol->create();
        if ($this->Sedol->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Sedol has been saved.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add sedol.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
    }
    $this->set('ipsAssets', $this->Sedol->IpsAsset->find('list'));
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Edit: looking at the debugger the post data is there, it's just no getting picked up...

Edit2: To clarify when I make the validation error in question it results when the form is submitted: the page reloads and the input with the error is highlighted in red. The issue doesn't occur with a pre-submit validation check - i.e. a tooltip to alert of wrong data.

Comment: seems like the form still contains validation errors. Try to display  validation errors array. Also make sure cake debug is on

Comment: You can display error in the controller like [http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html)

Comment: Upon viewing the validation errors in the debug console all are empty signifying no validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

In your action try to

```
if ($this->Sedol->save($this->request->data)) {
// code
}
pr($this->Sedol->validationErrors);
```

It will answer why form is not saving

Comment: As said in previous comment, there is no validation error. The problem occurs after correcting a validation error and resubmitting.

Comment: Have you checked the validationErrors property??
If yes try to see which data you have in beforeSave event

function beforeSave()
{
     pr($this->data);
     exit;
}

Check if the code reaches here